# f# web api HttpModule

Tags: f#

I am trying to write my own httpModule in f# web api, I am using visual studio 2015. I was able write the code in C# but when I try same code in f# , I get error that it is unable to load class from assembly

TestHttpMod1 is class name derived from IHttpModule,
TestHttpMod is module name
FSharp is namespace
FSharp is workspace name.

I have 2 questions
Can I get some reference code in F# where HttpModule is implemented in web api
or
How to solve the error?(exact error is as below)

`"Could not load type 'FSharp.TestHttpMod.TestHttpMod1' from assembly 'FSharp'."`

Below is configuration done in web config

```
<modules>
      <add name="TestHttpMod1" type ="FSharp.TestHttpMod.TestHttpMod1, FSharp"/>
<modules/>
```

Regards,
Amit Bhagwat

Comment: There is so much to check and make sure. Is there a file named `FSharp.dll` in your `bin` folder? If you attach a debugger and catch the exception, does it have an `InnerException`? If you open the `FSharp.dll` with ILSpy, can you find your class under that specific path?

Comment: Hi, I looked the path under ILSpy it was showing TestHttpMod module as static class, I removed the module and directly added class inside the namepace and checked the dll in ILSpy this time static class (which was module) was not there, now have namespace.classname in config file and it worked fine. Thanks a lot for directions.